# having trouble with arrays and maybe split

Tags: java, arrays, split

```
String realstring = "&&&.&&&&";
Double value = 555.55555;
String[] arraystring = realstring.split(".");
String stringvalue = String.valueof(value);
String [] valuearrayed = stringvalue.split(".");
System.out.println(arraystring[0]);
```

Sorry if it looks bad. Rewrote on my phone. I keep getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` at the `System.out.println`. I have looked and can't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: split takes a regexp as argument, not a literal string. You have to escape the dot. Or you could also simply use indexOf('.') and substring().

Comment: @JBNizet I feel like that should be the answer :)

Comment: I succumbed to the pressure :)

Comment: @JBNizet can you explain more

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Are you sure? I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` from that link.

Comment: @PaulBellora: And now, so do I. (Comment deleted, but here's the link: http://ideone.com/mCBYAV) How weird. Well, IDEOne's UI is so disjointed, I probably misread it. (Still a very handy tool.) Weird that it returns an empty array, but I just read your now-deleted comment ("Splitting on `.` means splitting on any character, and by default `split` leaves off trailing empty strings, and splitting on any character gives you *only* empty strings" or something like that) on JB's answer, and that explains it nicely!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`split()` takes a regexp as argument, not a literal string. You have to escape the dot:

```
string.split("\\.");
```

or

```
string.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

Or you could also simply use `indexOf('.')` and `substring()` to get the two parts of your string.

And if the goal is to get the integer part of a double, you could also simply use

```
long truncated = (long) doubleValue;
```

Comment: But why was the array empty? That's the other half of the puzzle :)

Comment: I'll let you add an answer for that. I hate regexps :)

Comment: To split, I really prefer using Guava's Splitter, which is more logical, predictable, efficient and easy to use: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter

Answer (score 7):

`split` uses regex as parameter and in regex `.` means "any character except line separators", so you could expect that `"a.bc".split(".")` would create array of empty strings like  `["","","","",""]`. Only reason it is not happening is because (from `split` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

so because all strings are empty you get empty array (and that is because you see `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

To turn off removal mechanism you would have to use `split(regex, limit)` version with negative `limit`.

To split on `.` literal you need to escape it with `\.` (which in Java needs to be written as `"\\."` because `\` is also Strings metacharacter)  or `[.]` or other regex mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Dot (.) is a special character so you need to escape it.

```
String realstring = "&&&.&&&&";         
String[] partsOfString = realstring.split("\\.");
String part1 = partsOfString[0];
String part2 = partsOfString[1];
System.out.println(part1);
```

this will print expected result of

> &&&

Its also handy to test if given string contains this character. You can do this by doing :

```
if (string.contains(".")) {
    // Split it.
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string + " does not contain .");
}
```